# Alexa Flash Briefing Skill => not available (maybe timeout?)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, alexa-skills-kit

I developed a Flash Briefing Skill for Alexa.
As URL i entered an URL for AWS API Gateway, which uses my Lambda to create dynamically the JSON Content.

My Problem is, that sometimes, i get an error from alexa that my skill is currently not available. 
If i try it again, it works.

after some time, the same problem occurs again. In the Log for the Lambda Function, i see that the Lambda was executed successfully. And the Time was < 2 seconds.

Currently i have the feeling that it always occured when the Lambda is not cached. Is it possible that the initialization of the lambda container, needs so many time, that i get a timeout for my skill?

it seems to be only a problem for flash briefing skills...

but i can't find any log for the skill itself. only for the lambda function which seems fine.

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the loading/initialization of the lambda container needs to long time.
i give the Lambda Function more Memory. => because with more memory, the Lambda get also more cpu speed.

With more CPU Speed the Problem is solved.

Kind Regards
Stefan